# Core-bridge configuration using two different hosts: hornetq HQ119013

Tags: java, networking, jms, hornetq, jboss-messaging

We face the following problem with core-bridge and hornetq and would appreciate any help.

## Situation:

We have standalone hornetq server, say QSA, and another hornetq server, say QSB.
The goal is to have qeues bridged in that way that a message sent to queue on QSA/queue

Hornetq Servers are both hornetq-2.4.0.Final and running standalon, non-clustered.

On QSA we have two queues relevant:

- queue/datahub/switched
- queue/datahub/switchedinquiry-send

On QSA we also have tow queues relevant:

- queue/smartcontrol/switchedinquiry
- queue/smartcontrol/switched-send

The Bridge should now work as follow:

- QSA:/queue/datahub/switchedinquiry-send -->Bridge--> QSB:queue/smartcontrol/switchedinquiry
- QSB:queue/smartcontrol/switched-send -->Bridge--> QSA:qeue/datahub/switched

## Problem:

When QSA and QSA are running on the same host and configured by either using the IP or the Loopback (localhost) everything works fine.

**But what we want is, that QSA and QSB are running on different hosts using different ips. Heres where the problem arises: **

```
HornetQConnectionTimedOutException[errorType=CONNECTION_TIMEDOUT message=HQ119013: Timed out waiting to receive cluster topology. Group:null]


16 Jul 2014 12:09:16,622 DEBUG [Thread-20 (HornetQ-server-HornetQServerImpl::serverUUID=6cdc0a86-083b-11e4-84ef-c3d4fbb03c17-103207534)] org.hornetq.core.server.cluster.impl.BridgeImpl:977 - Bridge BridgeImpl@65719a42 [name=inquiry.bridge, queue=QueueImpl[name=jms.queue.datahub.switchedinquiry-send, postOffice=PostOfficeImpl [server=HornetQServerImpl::serverUUID=6cdc0a86-083b-11e4-84ef-c3d4fbb03c17]]@7c25984b targetConnector=ServerLocatorImpl (identity=Bridge inquiry.bridge) [initialConnectors=[TransportConfiguration(name=remote-connector, factory=org-hornetq-core-remoting-impl-netty-NettyConnectorFactory) ?port=5446&host=10-254-8-1], discoveryGroupConfiguration=null]] is unable to connect to destination. Retrying: HornetQConnectionTimedOutException[errorType=CONNECTION_TIMEDOUT message=HQ119013: Timed out waiting to receive cluster topology. Group:null]
    at org.hornetq.core.client.impl.ServerLocatorImpl.createSessionFactory(ServerLocatorImpl.java:950) [hornetq-core-client.jar:]
    at org.hornetq.core.server.cluster.impl.BridgeImpl.createSessionFactory(BridgeImpl.java:820) [hornetq-server.jar:]
    at org.hornetq.core.server.cluster.impl.BridgeImpl.connect(BridgeImpl.java:890) [hornetq-server.jar:]
    at org.hornetq.core.server.cluster.impl.BridgeImpl$ConnectRunnable.run(BridgeImpl.java:1108) [hornetq-server.jar:]
    at org.hornetq.utils.OrderedExecutorFactory$OrderedExecutor$1.run(OrderedExecutorFactory.java:107) [hornetq-core-client.jar:]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
```

More or less the same Exception occurs using standard jms-bridge, even though the stacktrac is a bit longer:

There seems to be the same problem using standard jms-bridge.
Thje Stacktrace is a bit longer but all in all it is the sanme underlying exception:

```
HornetQConnectionTimedOutException[errorType=CONNECTION_TIMEDOUT message=HQ119013: Timed out waiting to receive cluster topology. Group:null]

16 Jul 2014 16:51:25,179 WARN  [main] org.hornetq.jms.bridge.impl.JMSBridgeImpl:1357 - HQ122010: Failed to connect JMS Bridge: javax.jms.JMSException: Failed to create session factory
    at org.hornetq.jms.client.HornetQConnectionFactory.createConnectionInternal(HornetQConnectionFactory.java:676) [hornetq-jms-client.jar:]
    at org.hornetq.jms.client.HornetQConnectionFactory.createXAConnection(HornetQConnectionFactory.java:208) [hornetq-jms-client.jar:]
    at org.hornetq.jms.client.HornetQConnectionFactory.createXAConnection(HornetQConnectionFactory.java:203) [hornetq-jms-client.jar:]
    at org.hornetq.jms.bridge.impl.JMSBridgeImpl.createConnection(JMSBridgeImpl.java:1104) [hornetq-jms-server.jar:]
    at org.hornetq.jms.bridge.impl.JMSBridgeImpl.setupJMSObjects(JMSBridgeImpl.java:1310) [hornetq-jms-server.jar:]
    at org.hornetq.jms.bridge.impl.JMSBridgeImpl.start(JMSBridgeImpl.java:415) [hornetq-jms-server.jar:]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at org.jboss.reflect.plugins.introspection.ReflectionUtils.invoke(ReflectionUtils.java:59) [jboss-mc.jar:]
    at org.jboss.reflect.plugins.introspection.ReflectMethodInfoImpl.invoke(ReflectMethodInfoImpl.java:150) [jboss-mc.jar:]
    at org.jboss.joinpoint.plugins.BasicMethodJoinPoint.dispatch(BasicMethodJoinPoint.java:66) [jboss-mc.jar:]
    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.KernelControllerContextAction$JoinpointDispatchWrapper.execute(KernelControllerContextAction.java:241) [jboss-mc.jar:]
    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.ExecutionWrapper.execute(ExecutionWrapper.java:47) [jboss-mc.jar:]
    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.KernelControllerContextAction.dispatchExecutionWrapper(KernelControllerContextAction.java:109) [jboss-mc.jar:]
    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.KernelControllerContextAction.dispatchJoinPoint(KernelControllerContextAction.java:70) [jboss-mc.jar:]
    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.LifecycleAction.installActionInternal(LifecycleAction.java:221) [jboss-mc.jar:]
    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.InstallsAwareAction.installAction(InstallsAwareAction.java:54) [jboss-mc.jar:]
    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.InstallsAwareAction.installAction(InstallsAwareAction.java:42) [jboss-mc.jar:]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.SimpleControllerContextAction.simpleInstallAction(SimpleControllerContextAction.java:62) [jboss-mc.jar:]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.AccessControllerContextAction.install(AccessControllerContextAction.java:71) [jboss-mc.jar:]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContextActions.install(AbstractControllerContextActions.java:51) [jboss-mc.jar:]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348) [jboss-mc.jar:]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1631) [jboss-mc.jar:]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:934) [jboss-mc.jar:]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082) [jboss-mc.jar:]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984) [jboss-mc.jar:]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:774) [jboss-mc.jar:]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:540) [jboss-mc.jar:]
    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.deployment.AbstractKernelDeployer.deployBean(AbstractKernelDeployer.java:319) [jboss-mc.jar:]
    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.deployment.AbstractKernelDeployer.deployBeans(AbstractKernelDeployer.java:297) [jboss-mc.jar:]
    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.deployment.AbstractKernelDeployer.deploy(AbstractKernelDeployer.java:130) [jboss-mc.jar:]
    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.deployment.xml.BeanXMLDeployer.deploy(BeanXMLDeployer.java:96) [jboss-mc.jar:]
    at org.hornetq.integration.bootstrap.HornetQBootstrapServer.deploy(HornetQBootstrapServer.java:236) [hornetq-bootstrap.jar:]
    at org.hornetq.integration.bootstrap.HornetQBootstrapServer.deploy(HornetQBootstrapServer.java:206) [hornetq-bootstrap.jar:]
    at org.hornetq.integration.bootstrap.HornetQBootstrapServer.bootstrap(HornetQBootstrapServer.java:154) [hornetq-bootstrap.jar:]
    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.bootstrap.AbstractBootstrap.run(AbstractBootstrap.java:83) [jboss-mc.jar:]
    at org.hornetq.integration.bootstrap.HornetQBootstrapServer.run(HornetQBootstrapServer.java:115) [hornetq-bootstrap.jar:]
    at org.hornetq.integration.bootstrap.HornetQBootstrapServer.main(HornetQBootstrapServer.java:69) [hornetq-bootstrap.jar:]
Caused by: HornetQConnectionTimedOutException[errorType=CONNECTION_TIMEDOUT message=HQ119013: Timed out waiting to receive cluster topology. Group:null]
    at org.hornetq.core.client.impl.ServerLocatorImpl.createSessionFactory(ServerLocatorImpl.java:950) [hornetq-core-client.jar:]
    at org.hornetq.jms.client.HornetQConnectionFactory.createConnectionInternal(HornetQConnectionFactory.java:672) [hornetq-jms-client.jar:]
    ... 39 more
```

## Question

1.) Why does this configuration run, if both hornetq servers run on same machine, but does not when running on different machines.
2.) How can we achieve the desired behaviour (discribed in Situation) with hornetq.

## Configuration:

The following configuration files where used. The configuration provided here works if both hornetq run on same machine. But if we adapt ip an place one server to another machine. The described problem occurs.

### QSA

#### hornetq-beans.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<deployment xmlns="urn:jboss:bean-deployer:2.0">
        <!-- MBean server -->
        <bean name="MBeanServer" class="javax.management.MBeanServer">
                <constructor factoryClass="java.lang.management.ManagementFactory"
                        factoryMethod="getPlatformMBeanServer" />
        </bean>
        <!-- The core configuration -->
        <bean name="Configuration" class="org.hornetq.core.config.impl.FileConfiguration">
        </bean>
        <!-- The security manager -->
        <bean name="HornetQSecurityManager"
                class="org.hornetq.spi.core.security.HornetQSecurityManagerImpl">
                <start ignored="true" />
                <stop ignored="true" />
        </bean>
        <!-- The core server -->
        <bean name="HornetQServer" class="org.hornetq.core.server.impl.HornetQServerImpl">
                <constructor>
                        <parameter>
                                <inject bean="Configuration" />
                        </parameter>
                        <parameter>
                                <inject bean="MBeanServer" />
                        </parameter>
                        <parameter>
                                <inject bean="HornetQSecurityManager" />
                        </parameter>
                </constructor>
                <start ignored="true" />
                <stop ignored="true" />
        </bean>
        <!-- The Stand alone server that controls the jndi server -->
        <bean name="StandaloneServer" class="org.hornetq.jms.server.impl.StandaloneNamingServer">
                <constructor>
                        <parameter>
                                <inject bean="HornetQServer" />
                        </parameter>
                </constructor>
                <property name="port">${jnp.port:41099}</property>
                <property name="bindAddress">${jnp.host:159.232.217.119}</property>
                <property name="rmiPort">${jnp.rmiPort:41098}</property>
                <property name="rmiBindAddress">${jnp.host:159.232.217.119}</property>
        </bean>
        <!-- The JMS server -->
        <bean name="JMSServerManager" class="org.hornetq.jms.server.impl.JMSServerManagerImpl">
                <constructor>
                        <parameter>
                                <inject bean="HornetQServer" />
                        </parameter>
                </constructor>
        </bean>
</deployment>
```

#### hornetq-configuration.xml

```
<configuration xmlns="urn:hornetq"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="urn:hornetq/schema/hornetq-configuration.xsd">
        <paging-directory>${data.dir:../data}/paging_dh</paging-directory>
        <bindings-directory>${data.dir:../data}/bindings_dh
        </bindings-directory>
        <journal-directory>${data.dir:../data}/journal_dh</journal-directory>
        <journal-min-files>10</journal-min-files>
        <large-messages-directory>${data.dir:../data}/large-messages_dh
        </large-messages-directory>
        <!-- Connectors -->
        <connectors>
                <connector name="netty-connector">
                        <factory-class>org.hornetq.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyConnectorFactory
                        </factory-class>
                        <param key="port" value="5445" />
                        <param key="host" value="159.232.217.119" />
                </connector>
                <!-- Connector to the other node -->
                <connector name="remote-connector">
                        <factory-class>org.hornetq.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyConnectorFactory
                        </factory-class>
                        <param key="port" value="5446" />
                        <param key="host" value="159.232.217.119" />
                        <!-- <param key="host" value="10.254.8.1"/> -->
                </connector>
        </connectors>
        <!-- Acceptors -->
        <acceptors>
                <acceptor name="netty-acceptor">
                        <factory-class>org.hornetq.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyAcceptorFactory
                        </factory-class>
                        <param key="port" value="5445" />
                        <param key="host" value="159.232.217.119" />
                </acceptor>
        </acceptors>
        <queues>
                <queue name="jms.queue.smartcontrol.switchedinquiry">
                        <address>jms.queue.smartcontrol.switchedinquiry</address>
                        <durable>true</durable>
                </queue>
                <queue name="jms.queue.datahub.switchedinquiry-send">
                        <address>jms.queue.datahub.switchedinquiry-send</address>
                        <durable>true</durable>
                </queue>
        </queues>
        <!-- We set-up a bridge that forwards from a queue on this node to an address
                on another node. We specify a filter with the bridge, and a transformer too.
                The filter and transformer are optional -->
        <bridges>
                <bridge name="inquiry.bridge">
                        <queue-name>jms.queue.datahub.switchedinquiry-send</queue-name>
                        <forwarding-address>jms.queue.smartcontrol.switchedinquiry
                        </forwarding-address>
                        <reconnect-attempts>-1</reconnect-attempts>
                        <static-connectors>
                                <connector-ref>remote-connector</connector-ref>
                        </static-connectors>
                </bridge>
        </bridges>
        <security-settings>
                <!--security for example queue -->
                <security-setting match="jms.queue.#">
                        <permission type="createDurableQueue" roles="guest" />
                        <permission type="deleteDurableQueue" roles="guest" />
                        <permission type="createNonDurableQueue" roles="guest" />
                        <permission type="deleteNonDurableQueue" roles="guest" />
                        <permission type="consume" roles="guest" />
                        <permission type="send" roles="guest" />
                </security-setting>
        </security-settings>
        <address-settings>
                <address-setting match="jms.queue.smartcontrol.switchedinquiry">
                        <dead-letter-address>jms.queue.smartcontrol.switchedinquiryDLQ
                        </dead-letter-address>
                        <max-size-bytes>262144000</max-size-bytes>
                        <page-size-bytes>10485760</page-size-bytes>
                        <address-full-policy>PAGE</address-full-policy>
                </address-setting>
        </address-settings>
</configuration>
```

#### hornetq-jms.xml

```
<configuration xmlns="urn:hornetq"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="urn:hornetq /schema/hornetq-jms.xsd">
        <connection-factory name="ConnectionFactory">
                <connectors>
                        <connector-ref connector-name="netty-connector" />
                </connectors>
                <entries>
                        <entry name="ConnectionFactory" />
                </entries>
        </connection-factory>
        <queue name="datahub.switched">
                <entry name="queue/datahub/switched" />
        </queue>
        <queue name="datahub.switchedinquiry-send">
                <entry name="queue/datahub/switchedinquiry-send" />
        </queue>
</configuration>
```

### QSB

#### hornetq-beans.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<deployment xmlns="urn:jboss:bean-deployer:2.0">
        <!-- MBean server -->
        <bean name="MBeanServer" class="javax.management.MBeanServer">
                <constructor factoryClass="java.lang.management.ManagementFactory"
                        factoryMethod="getPlatformMBeanServer" />
        </bean>
        <!-- The core configuration -->
        <bean name="Configuration" class="org.hornetq.core.config.impl.FileConfiguration">
        </bean>
        <!-- The security manager -->
        <bean name="HornetQSecurityManager"
                class="org.hornetq.spi.core.security.HornetQSecurityManagerImpl">
                <start ignored="true" />
                <stop ignored="true" />
        </bean>
        <!-- The core server -->
        <bean name="HornetQServer" class="org.hornetq.core.server.impl.HornetQServerImpl">
                <constructor>
                        <parameter>
                                <inject bean="Configuration" />
                        </parameter>
                        <parameter>
                                <inject bean="MBeanServer" />
                        </parameter>
                        <parameter>
                                <inject bean="HornetQSecurityManager" />
                        </parameter>
                </constructor>
                <start ignored="true" />
                <stop ignored="true" />
        </bean>
        <!-- The Stand alone server that controls the jndi server -->
        <bean name="StandaloneServer" class="org.hornetq.jms.server.impl.StandaloneNamingServer">
                <constructor>
                        <parameter>
                                <inject bean="HornetQServer" />
                        </parameter>
                </constructor>
                <property name="port">${jnp.port:1099}</property>
                <property name="bindAddress">${jnp.host:159.232.217.119}</property>
                <property name="rmiPort">${jnp.rmiPort:1098}</property>
                <property name="rmiBindAddress">${jnp.host:159.232.217.119}</property>
        </bean>
        <!-- The JMS server -->
        <bean name="JMSServerManager" class="org.hornetq.jms.server.impl.JMSServerManagerImpl">
                <constructor>
                        <parameter>
                                <inject bean="HornetQServer" />
                        </parameter>
                </constructor>
        </bean>
</deployment>
```

#### hornetq-configuration.xml

```
<configuration xmlns="urn:hornetq"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="urn:hornetq /schema/hornetq-configuration.xsd">
        <paging-directory>${data.dir:../data}/paging_rsa</paging-directory>
        <bindings-directory>${data.dir:../data}/bindings_rsa
        </bindings-directory>
        <journal-directory>${data.dir:../data}/journal_rsa</journal-directory>
        <journal-min-files>10</journal-min-files>
        <large-messages-directory>${data.dir:../data}/large-messages_rsa
        </large-messages-directory>
        <connectors>
                <connector name="netty-connector">
                        <factory-class>org.hornetq.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyConnectorFactory
                        </factory-class>
                        <param key="port" value="5446" />
                        <param key="host" value="159.232.217.119" />
                </connector>
                <!-- Connector to the other node -->
                <connector name="remote-connector-bridge">
                        <factory-class>org.hornetq.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyConnectorFactory
                        </factory-class>
                        <param key="port" value="5445" />
                        <!-- <param key="host" value="159.232.3.62" /> -->
                        <param key="host" value="159.232.217.119" />
                </connector>
        </connectors>
        <!-- Acceptors -->
        <acceptors>
                <acceptor name="netty-acceptor">
                        <factory-class>org.hornetq.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyAcceptorFactory
                        </factory-class>
                        <param key="port" value="5446" />
                        <param key="host" value="159.232.217.119" />
                </acceptor>
        </acceptors>
        <queues>
                <!-- rsa queues -->
                <queue name="jms.queue.smartcontrol.switched-send">
                        <address>jms.queue.smartcontrol.switched-send</address>
                        <durable>true</durable>
                </queue>
                <!-- datahub queues -->
                <queue name="jms.queue.datahub.switched">
                        <address>jms.queue.datahub.switched</address>
                        <durable>true</durable>
                </queue>
        </queues>
        <!-- We set-up a bridge that forwards from a queue on this node to an address
                on another node. We specify a filter with the bridge, and a transformer too.
                The filter and transformer are optional -->
        <bridges>
                <bridge name="switched.bridge">
                        <queue-name>jms.queue.smartcontrol.switched-send</queue-name>
                        <forwarding-address>jms.queue.datahub.switched</forwarding-address>
                        <reconnect-attempts>-1</reconnect-attempts>
                        <static-connectors>
                                <connector-ref>remote-connector-bridge</connector-ref>
                        </static-connectors>
                </bridge>
        </bridges>
        <security-settings>
                <!--security for example queue -->
                <security-setting match="jms.queue.#">
                        <permission type="createDurableQueue" roles="guest" />
                        <permission type="deleteDurableQueue" roles="guest" />
                        <permission type="createNonDurableQueue" roles="guest" />
                        <permission type="deleteNonDurableQueue" roles="guest" />
                        <permission type="consume" roles="guest" />
                        <permission type="send" roles="guest" />
                </security-setting>
        </security-settings>
        <address-settings>
                <address-setting match="jms.queue.datahub.switched">
                        <dead-letter-address>jms.queue.datahub.switchedDLQ
                        </dead-letter-address>
                        <max-size-bytes>262144000</max-size-bytes>
                        <page-size-bytes>10485760</page-size-bytes>
                        <address-full-policy>PAGE</address-full-policy>
                </address-setting>
        </address-settings>
</configuration>
```

#### hornetq-jms.xml

```
<configuration xmlns="urn:hornetq"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="urn:hornetq /schema/hornetq-jms.xsd">
        <connection-factory name="ConnectionFactory">
                <connectors>
                        <connector-ref connector-name="netty-connector" />
                </connectors>
                <entries>
                        <entry name="ConnectionFactory" />
                </entries>
        </connection-factory>
        <queue name="smartcontrol.switched-send">
                <entry name="queue/smartcontrol/switched-send" />
        </queue>
        <queue name="smartcontrol.switchedinquiry">
                <entry name="queue/smartcontrol/switchedinquiry" />
        </queue>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Did you ever get anywhere with this?  I believe I have the same issue.